# find word in UIwebview

Tags: javascript, uiwebview

I am having WEbview and textfield. webview size is small(so all contents are not visible at a time) . i want to find a single word . My requirement is that suppose i enter a word in Textbox and then there are 10 occurences of that word. When i click on a button, focus should shift on occurences one by one(by click of a button).  if an occurence is at last , then that word should be visible when it's  chance comes(webview needs to be changed bcoz default webview will nt show last para)  . Pl. help in this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest achieved using javascript, have a look at this method [UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW21)

Using that you can call javascript functions inside the web view. You can even inject new functions into the page using the method - and then call those.